# Where to start with integration of Paypal into my events site?

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart

I am looking for an accessible, and up to date tutorial on using the Paypal API, but I am struggling to find anything.

I need to create a shopping cart of tickets for an event website (based in PHP, build on Wordpress), some with multiple option forms, but I don't really know where to begin.

Any pointers on a good place to start would be a great help.

Comment: Try google: [api reference](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference)

Comment: Hope below link will help you
(https://cms.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_overview)

Comment: Check the official PayPal developer network at https://www.x.com. If that doesnt give you the info you need, eMail PayPal. They are a commercial service so they should provide assistance to their paying customers.

Comment: Check this link , I found it very helpful . http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

You can start specifically with [Training](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/training) section, [download SDKs](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/sdks) (both PayPal API and PayPal Adaptive API are ok), and play with [sample codes](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/code_samples).

I've also heard many recommends for this book: [PayPal APIs: Up and Running](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920014386/?cmp=sc-orm-0636920014386-paypal). You may want to check it out, just more than a hundred pages.

I have started with this route too :).